# Merging 100 files on the basis of a column in R

Tags: r

I have dataframes (100) like these:

```
df1
  v1 v2 v3
1  1  2  a
2  2  3  b
3  3  4  c
4  4  5  d
5  3  5  e

df2
  v1 v2 v3
1  1  2  j
2  2  3  i
3  3  4  t
4  3  5  r

df3
  v1 v2 v3
1  2  3  t
2  2  4  g
3  6  7  i
4  8  9  t
```

Now, I want to merge them on the basis of the value in the third column and form a single file, such that, if there is a corresponding value in the third column, then there will be a value in the sequence else 0.
Therefore, the resulting file will be,

```
  v1 v2  v3
1  1  2 aj0
2  2  3 bit
3  2  4 00g
4  3  4 ct0
5  3  5 er0
6  4  5 d00
7  6  7 00i
8  8  9 00t
```

I was able to come up with a code for this which is as follows:

```
> df12 <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("v1", "v2"), all=TRUE)
> df123 <- merge(df12, df3, by=c("v1", "v2"), all=TRUE)
> df123$v3 <- paste0(df123[,3], df123[,4], df123[,5])
> df123$v3.x <- df123$v3.y <- NULL
> df123$v3 <- gsub("NA", "0", df123$v3)
```

However, I have 100 dataframes, how can I do it with them? Thanks!

Comment: Can you check whether your `list` ie `dfs` elements are unnamed?  I used `mget` so, the list elements gets the name of the datasets. ie. `df1`, `df2` etc.

Comment: The names of the files in my list are: `P1.txt, P2.txt, P3.txt, P4.txt...........P100.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

unnest(dfs,group) %>%
                  spread(group, v3, fill=0) %>% 
                    unite(v3, df1:df3, sep="")
 #  v1 v2  v3
 #1  1  2 aj0
 #2  2  3 bit
 #3  2  4 00g
 #4  3  4 ct0
 #5  3  5 er0
 #6  4  5 d00
 #7  6  7 00i
 #8  8  9 00t
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 dt <- rbindlist(Map(`cbind`,group=names(dfs),dfs))
 dcast.data.table(dt, v1+v2~group, value.var="v3", fill="0")[,
                list(v3=do.call(`paste0`, .SD)), by=list(v1,v2), .SDcols=names(dfs)]

 #   v1 v2  v3
 #1:  1  2 aj0
 #2:  2  3 bit
 #3:  2  4 00g
 #4:  3  4 ct0
 #5:  3  5 er0
 #6:  4  5 d00
 #7:  6  7 00i
 #8:  8  9 00t
```

#### Update

If you have files `P1.txt`, `P2.txt` etc, you can read the files into a list and then apply the above code.  Assuming that files are in the working directory

```
  files <- list.files(pattern="^P\\d+")
  dfs <-lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x, header=TRUE, sep="") #or use `fread` from `data.table`
  nm1 <- gsub("\\..*", "", files)
  dfs <- setNames(dfs, nm1)
```

You need to replace the `df1:df3` in the `dplyr` code to `P1:P100`

```
  unnest(dfs,group) %>%
              spread(group, v3, fill=0) %>% 
                unite(v3, P1:P100, sep="")


###data

df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L), v2 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 5L), v3 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")), .Names = c("v1", "v2", 
"v3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5"))

df2 <- structure(list(v1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), v2 = 2:5, v3 = c("j", 
"i", "t", "r")), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

df3 <- structure(list(v1 = c(2L, 2L, 6L, 8L), v2 = c(3L, 4L, 7L, 9L), 
 v3 = c("t", "g", "i", "t")), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

 dfs <- mget(ls(pattern="^df\\d+"))
```

Comment: @akrun I'll take this one as a lesson for dcast.data.table. I was going through the CRAN manual today and wanted to see an example. Here it is. Thanks, as usual. +1.

Comment: @akrun You really polish up codes, but this is already a good example. All information in this post is helpful to learn data.table.

Comment: @akrun I saw you using get and `mget` the other day, but I could not identify which posts they were; you answered so many questions! But this example is good enough to learn `mget`. Full of information.

Comment: @jazzurro Here I first thought that the data objects were already created, which was later found to be not the case.  Using `mget` gives the list elements the names of the object.  So, we don't have to go through the process of `setNames(lst,...)`.  It is a very nice function.

Comment: @akrun Yes, it is. Very useful function. I'll play with `get` and `mget` more.

Comment: @akrun Would it be possible to split `dcast.data.table(dt, v1+v2~group, value.var="v3", fill="0")[,list(v3=do.call(`paste0`, .SD)),by=list(v1,v2), .SDcols=names(dfs)]` into 2 pieces? Or do you have to write in the way you wrote?

Comment: @jazzurro Yes, you can split it to two. ie. `DT <- dcast.data.table(dt, ....., fill="0"); DT[,list(v3=...)]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `Reduce` operating on a list of data frames:

```
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)
merged <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by=c("v1", "v2"), all=T), dfs)
v3 <- gsub("NA", "0", apply(merged[,c(-1, -2)], 1, paste, collapse=""))
data.frame(v1=merged$v1, v2=merged$v2, v3)
#   v1 v2  v3
# 1  1  2 aj0
# 2  2  3 bit
# 3  2  4 00g
# 4  3  4 ct0
# 5  3  5 er0
# 6  4  5 d00
# 7  6  7 00i
# 8  8  9 00t
```

Comment: It shows the error that `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
Called from: .rs.breakOnError(TRUE)`. What might be the reason for this?